# How to check if a number is power of 2

Tags: prolog

I want to create a function that takes a number and checks if this number is power of 2.
Like:
fn(0) is no,
fn(1) is yes,
fn(2) is yes,
fn(3) is no
etc...
I tried to make a power function like power(N,K,R) but this doesn't work if I ask something like power(2,_,8). Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

If we use prolog we could do as follows:

```
pow2(X) :- X > 0 , 0 is X /\ (X-1).
```

Here `/\` is bitwise AND. So if `X` is a power of two, it looks like `1000...0` in binary, and therefore `X-1` is `111...1` and the bitwise AND is therefore `0`. It is straightforward to see that this only happens for powers of two.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyjKz8lP1y0uz/z/vyC/3EgjQlPBSlchQsFOwUBBB4gzi4Ec/RgFjQhdQ009qCJjIJMLwjKCs4w19QA)

Comment: I know OP already seems to be satisfied with a python answer, but since it was tagged with [tag:prolog] I thought I'd add a prolog answer for completeness' sake.